# dc.js Composite Graph - Plot New Line for Each Person

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Good Evening Everyone,

I'm trying to take the data from a database full of hour reports (name, timestamp, hours worked, etc.) and create a plot using dc.js to visualize the data. I would like the timestamp to be on the x-axis, the sum of hours for the particular timestamp on the y-axis, and a new bar graph for each unique name all on the same chart.

It appears based on my objectives that using crossfilter.js the timestamp should be my 'dimension' and then the sum of hours should be my 'group'.

Question 1, how would I then use the dimension and group to further split the data based on the person's name and then create a bar graph to add to my composite graph? I would like for the crossfilter.js functionality to remain intact so that if I add a date range tool or some other user controllable filter, everything updates accordingly.

Question 2, my timestamps are in MySQL datetime format: YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS so how would I go about dropping precision? For instance, if I want to combine all entries from the same day into one entry (day precision) or combine all entries in one month into a single entry (month precision).

Thanks in advance!

---- Added on 2017/01/28 16:06

To further clarify, I'm referencing the Crossfilter & DC APIs alongside the DC [NASDAQ](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) and [Composite](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/composite.html) examples. The Composite example has shown me how to place multiple line/bar charts on a single graph. On the composite chart I've created, each of the bar charts I've added a dimension based off of the timestamps in the data-set. Now I'm trying to figure out how to define the groups for each. I want each bar chart to represent the total time worked per timestamp.

For example, I have five people in my database, so I want there to be five bar charts within the single composite chart. Today all five submitted reports saying they worked 8 hours, so now all five bar charts should show a mark at 01/28/2017 on the x-axis and 8 hours on the y-axis.

```
    var parseDate = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').parse;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
    });
    var ndx              = crossfilter(data);
    var writtenDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.timestamp;
    });
    var hoursSumGroup    = writtenDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
      return d.time_total;
    });
    var minDate = parseDate('2017-01-01 00:00:00');
    var maxDate = parseDate('2017-01-31 23:59:59');
    var mybarChart = dc.compositeChart("#my_chart");
    mybarChart
      .width(window.innerWidth)
      .height(480)
      .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
      .brushOn(false)
      .clipPadding(10)
      .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
      .compose([
        dc.barChart(mybarChart)
            .dimension(writtenDimension)
            .colors('red')
            .group(hoursSumGroup, "Top Line")
      ]);
```

So based on what I have right now and the example I've provided, in the compose section I should have 5 charts because there are 5 people (obviously this needs to be dynamic in the end) and each of those charts should only show the timestamp: total_time data for that person.

At this point I don't know how to further breakup the group hoursSumGroup based on each person and this is where my Question #1 comes in and I need help figuring out.

Question #2 above is that I want to make sure that the code is both dynamic (more people can be handled without code change), when minDate and maxDate are later tied to user input fields, the charts update automatically (I assume through adjusting the dimension variable in some way), and if I add a names filter that if I unselect names that the chart will update by removing the data for that person.

A Question #3 that I'm now realizing I'll want to figure out is how to get the person's name to show up in the pointer tooltip (the title) along with timestamp and total_time values.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO and dc.js! I'm not sure what you mean with all the mentions of bars - are you looking for a [line series chart](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html)? Also look at the [switching time intervals example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html) for an idea how to aggregate by day or month. Finally, here's the [documentation for d3.time.format.parse](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#parse), for turning your strings into date objects.

Comment: As this stands this is not a great question, it's better around here to jump in and start coding and wait till you get stuck before asking for help. If you want a more leisurely discussion, feel free to reach out [on the users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group). I didn't leave the close vote but I'd say this is a little broad as it stands.

Comment: Gordon, I've updated my question above in response to your comments. Are the changes sufficient enough to get you a better picture of what I'm looking to do?

Comment: That helps a lot! I'm still confused about the composite bar chart - it sounds like you want 5 charts but the composite would put them all on top of each other. Maybe you mean to generate 5 charts instead? That's pretty easy but it's out of scope for what dc.js does on its own.

Comment: Let's focus on question 1 here - I think the rest of this will just fall out of the way dc.js naturally works. (Or is covered by other questions that have been answered already elsewhere.)

Comment: I'm definitely intending for all 5 charts to be on one chart. The end goal being that I can see and be able to distinguish everyone's totals all at one time. As it is above, I can plot the total all lumped together, but have no way to distinguish. I have managed to conjure up one method that creates a chart for each person; I loop through a list of names generating a new barChart object for each person and a reduceSum where I manually set to 0 the return value when name doesn't match the current name, but I'm thinking this will break crossfilter functionality.

Comment: So you want line charts not bar charts right? Or are you looking for [grouped bars](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1043)? Or [stacked bars](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html)? Because regular bars don't compose well.

Comment: I was trying to use regular bars, but lines would work too, it's only a few lines different in the code. Grouped bars may be of interest later on. I presume no matter which chart type I go with that I'll still have the same underlying issue to figure out?

Comment: Well unfortunately there are different mechanisms for them, so no, not entirely the same. dc.js wasn't wasn't exactly planned out from the start. I guess I'll address how to do a composite line chart. It's the weekend so I may not get to this until Monday. I don't think it will be much different from the series example I linked above, except that the x axis is dates not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about this, but I think the easiest thing to do is to create a custom reduction which reduces each person into a sub-bin.

First off, addressing question #2, you'll want to set up your dimension based on the time interval you're interested in. For instance, if you're looking at days:

```
var writtenDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d3.time.hour(d.timestamp);
});
chart.xUnits(d3.time.hours);
```

This will cause each timestamp to be rounded down to the nearest hour, and tell the chart to calculate the bar width accordingly.

Next, here's a custom reduction ([from the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#what-if-rows-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row)) which will create an object for each reduced value, with values for each person's name:

```
var hoursSumGroup = writtenDimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.name] = (p[v.name] || 0) + d.time_total;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.name] -= d.time_total;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // init
        return {};
    });
```

I did not go with the series example I mentioned in the comments, because I think composite keys can be difficult to deal with. That's another option, and I'll expand my answer if that's necessary.

Next, we can feed the composite line charts with value accessors that can fetch the value by name.

Assume we have an array `names`.

```
compositeChart.shareTitle(false);
compositeChart.compose(
    names.map(function(name) {
        return dc.lineChart(compositeChart)
            .dimension(writtenDimension)
            .colors('red')
            .group(hoursSumGroup)
            .valueAccessor(function(kv) {
                return kv.value[name];
            })
            .title(function(kv) {
                return name + ' ' + kv.key + ': ' + kv.value;
            });
    }));
```

Again, it wouldn't make sense to use bar charts here, because they would obscure each other.

If you filter a name elsewhere, it will cause the line for the name to drop to zero. Having the line disappear entirely would probably not be so simple.

The above `shareTitle(false)` ensures that the child charts will draw their own titles; the `title` functions just add the current name to those titles (which would usually just be key:value).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I've done something very similar to this and works nicely!